# Laravel Postgre sql returning ************0

Tags: laravel, postgresql, eloquent

I have a problem selecting a database:

`id_service_point | 103 code | 31.73.01.0000`

My query is:

```
DB::table("zonasi_service_point")->select(["id_service_point", "code"])->where('id_service_point', 103)->first();
```

My Return value is

`{"id_service_point":"103","code":"************0"}"`

The problem comes when the field has multiple dot characters.

Comment: What is your field type for "code" column and your Collation for the same ?

Comment: The type is character varrying. I think that the field have same format as ip address format